# The group $\langle a,b,c \ | a^3,b^2, ab=ba^2, c^2, ac=ca, bc=cb \rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

The group $\langle a,b,c \ | a^3,b^2, ab=ba^2, c^2, ac=ca, bc=cb \rangle$ is isomorphic to which permutation group.

I have calculated its order and it is $12$, so my guess was $A_4$ but it is not working out as I tried  to satisfy relations, which group it is isomorphic to?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $c$ commutes with $a$ and $b$, so we have immediately that

$G=\langle a,b,c \ | a^3,b^2, ab=ba^2, c^2, ac=ca, bc=cb\rangle = H \oplus \langle c \ | c^2=1 \rangle = H \oplus \, \mathbb{Z}_2$

for some group $H$ of order 6. So how many groups of order 6 are there...?

Comment: It is $S_3 $.... thanks.. got it

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: Nitpicking: isn't a little odd to use the symbol for direct *sum* when working with neither abelian nor additively-written groups?

Comment: @Timbuc That is possible, but I wasn't familiar with that convention. I think when I first learned it in Gallian, the oplus notation is used for internal (as opposed to external) direct sum, so perhaps that stuck with me. In any case, the direct sum and direct product are isomorphic in the case of finitely many summands, so hopefully it is not too disturbing too anyone.

Comment: @Max, it really doesn't matter. That's why I wrote "nitpicking" .Fine answer.

Comment: @Timbuc Nitpicking is fine with me! It is worth thinking about such things as to try to be as clear as possible to your audience. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $G = \langle a,b,c |a^3,b^2,ab=ba^2,c^2,ac=ca,bc=cb\rangle$.  The subgroup $H$ generated by $\{a,b\}$ is isomorphic to $S_3$.  The element $c$ commutes with $H$, and so lies in the center of $G$, which intersects $H$ trivially (since $H$ has trivial center).  So $G$ is the direct product $H \times \langle c\rangle$.

This group is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$, since in $S_4$ there are no pairs of commuting elements $a,c$ such that $a$ has order 3 and $c$ has order 2.

This group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_5$.  Let $H$ be the subgroup which fixes the last two points, and let $c$ be the transposition which interchanges the last two points.

Comment: Very nice, in particular the pointing that the group is not isomorphic to a subgroup of S_4. One could also add that it can't be since $\;|H\times \langle c\rangle|=12\;$ so if the group was a sbgp. of $\;S_4\;$ it'd have to be $\;A_4\;$ , yet this last group has **no** subgroup of order $\;6\;$ . +1